# How do I evaluate this integral: $ \ \int (x^2-1)/ \ln(x) \ \ dx \ \ $?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

This is the integral that I have to evaluate:

**How do I evaluate the indefinite integral?**
$$ \int \ \frac{x^2  -  1}{\ln x} \ \ dx \ \ . $$

I was just looking up for some 'tough integrals' to practice on youtube and then this video shows up:

[The Source](https://youtu.be/aJLJNF4MrVg)

This guy allegedly uses the Feynman integral trick and I mostly understand what he is writing.

**But is there a way the definite integral can be done without using the trick?** (as tricks are generally shortcuts.)

It seems extremely hard to do without the trick. I could barely scratch the surface(maybe).

Comment: Feynman's trick is usually used to evaluate definite integrals. In this case the antiderivative of the integrand is $\operatorname{Ei}_1(-\log x) - \operatorname{Ei}_1(-3 \log x)$. Did you mean to ask about, e.g., the definite integral over $[0, 1]$?

Comment: @TravisWillse  Won't the definite integral be computed after the indefinite is found?

Comment: All integrals are not necessarily computed using antiderivatives.

Comment: There edited it to make it more general and include both

Comment: How are tricks shortcuts? They are simply a way to solve something.

Comment: @Aurelius Yes, of course. It's sometimes the case, though, (as it is here) that the general antiderivative of the integrand cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions and basic constants, but particular definite integrals of that integral can.

Comment: Substituting $x = e^{-t}, dx = -e^{-t} \,dt $ transforms the definite integral into
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t} - e^{-3 t}}{t}\,dt = \int_0^\infty \int_1^3 e^{-st} \,ds \,dt = \int_1^3 \int_0^\infty e^{-st} \,ds \,dt = \int_1^3 \frac{dt}{t} = \log 3.$$ (The second equality invokes Tonelli's Theorem.) Perhaps despite appearances, it's actually Feynman's trick again, this time written in terms of an iterated integral. The integral in $t$, by the way, is a Frullani integral, which can in principle always be evaluated using this trick. tthttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral

Answer (score 1):

$\int \frac{x^2-1}{\ln x} dx.$ $e^u=x. e^udu=dx$

$\int \frac{e^{2u}-1}{u}e^u du=\int \frac{3e^{3u}du}{3u}-\int \frac{e^udu}{u}$

$v=3u. dv=3du$

$\int \frac{e^vdv}{v}-\int \frac{e^udu}{u}=C$

I think that's it.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int \ \frac{x^2  -  1}{\log( x)} \, dx $$
$$x=e^t \quad \implies \quad I=\int \frac{e^t(e^{2t}-1)} t \,dt$$
$$I=\int \frac{e^{3t}}{3t}\,d(3t)-\int \frac{e^{t}}{t}\,dt$$
$$\int\frac{e^{t}}{t}\,dt=\text{Ei}(t)$$ where appears the exponential integral function.